# Add tabber to rmarkdown navbar

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, navbar, flexdashboard

I created a drop-down menu as in this repex ([Prevent navigation bar from overlapping content in flexdashboard R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914936/prevent-navigation-bar-from-overlapping-content-in-flexdashboard-r)):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```


Long Tab 1 {data-navmenu="Project Sections"}
============================================================
### Chart A

```{r}

```


Another Long Tab 2 {data-navmenu="Project Sections"}
============================================================
Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

```



Another Long Tab 3
============================================================
### Chart C

```{r}




Another Long Tab 4
============================================================




Another Long Tab 5
============================================================




Another Long Tab 6
============================================================
```
````

However, I'd like to also have a tabber next to the dropdown "Project Sections" showing which chart I have currently selected (eg. Project Sections Chart B).[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to have a submenu in the dropdown menu?

Comment: I edited my post to show the desired changes with a picture :)